# How do I say “always remembered” on a locket with a picture of my Dad?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

To engrave on a locket with a photo of my father after his death

Answer (score 1):

To remove potential ambiguities you could try:

"numquam memoria excides." =

(literally) "You will never fall out of memory." = "You will never be forgotten."

Alternatively, using the infinitive of "excido":

"numquam memoria excidere." =

"Never to be forgotten."

(An active verb translated passively.)

Answer (score 0):

'Remembered' is a past particle. One way to translate 'to remember' is 'memorare'. I would go with a particle perfect passive, as it is a person who is being remembered, but I'm not really sure about this. Maybe someone else can give a better alternative for the verb form.

So the translation would then be:

Semper memorato

Comment: The problem I see with this is that it basically means "always brought up, mentioned," does it not?

Comment: My first reading of your suggestion was a future imperative: "always remember". That is not a particularly harmful ambiguity, and can even be considered beneficial.

Comment: Thank you for your input - is there a general consensus on what might be appropriate/correct to engrave?